# Vala gstreamer link failed

Tags: linux, gstreamer, pipeline, vala

I've a problem with playing a mjpeg stream in vala.

I have construct my pipeline and it works with only two elements(videotestsrc and cluttersink), but if I want to add more I get an "Internal data flow error" and "streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)".
If I run the pipeline manually it works:

```
gst-launch souphttpsrc location=http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg !  multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

Here is my streaming class:

```
public class Stream : Clutter.Actor {

    Clutter.Texture video;

    public dynamic Gst.Element playbin;


    public Gst.Pipeline pipeline;
    public  Gst.Element demux;
    public  Gst.Element jpegdec;
    public  Gst.Element outputsink;

    public  dynamic Gst.Element src;
    public  dynamic Gst.Element video_sink;

    public Stream(){

        print("stream");
        video = new Clutter.Texture ();

        this.pipeline = new Gst.Pipeline("videopipeline");
        this.src = Gst.ElementFactory.make ("souphttpsrc","httpsrc");
        this.demux = Gst.ElementFactory.make ("multipartdemux","demux");
        this.jpegdec = Gst.ElementFactory.make ("jpegdec","jpegdec");
        this.outputsink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autovideosink","output");    
        this.video_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make ("cluttersink", "source");

        this.video_sink.texture = video;

        this.src.set("location","http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg");


        this.pipeline.add_many(this.src,this.demux,this.jpegdec,this.outputsink,this.video_sink);
        this.src.link(this.demux);
        this.demux.link(this.jpegdec);
        this.jpegdec.link(this.outputsink);
        this.outputsink.link(this.video_sink);

        this.add_child (video);

        this.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING);

    }





}
```

Here is the full error log: 
http://pastebin.com/b9GnA5ke

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two sink elements attached to jpegdec.  If you need to do that you should use the "tee" element, while making sure to use add a "queue" to each branch of the tee.

There may also be a caps issue going from jpegdec to cluttersink.  I'd structure it as follows:

> ```
> souphttpsrc !  multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! tee name=t ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
>
> t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! cluttersink
> ```

Comment: Thanks I've tried this but it didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Can you paste your updated pipeline for the tee?  Can you also do "gst-inspect cluttersink" on the command line?  I can't find a doc for its caps.